# How can i specify the width for autocomplete in percentage?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to add the width in this jquery code with percentage, but it is taking the width in pixels. how can i specify the width in percentage?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var autocm = jQuery.noConflict();
autocm().ready(function() {
    autocm("#search").autocomplete("php/getvalues.php", {
        width: 500,
        matchContains: true,
        //mustMatch: false,
        //minChars: 0,
        //multiple: true,
        //highlight: true,
        //multipleSeparator: ",",
        selectFirst: false
    });
});(autocm);
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding it in percentages:

```
    width:'50%',
```

Comment: for the same, how can i specify , if screen size is < than 480px; then width:80%. ?